Solve for $x$: $x\lfloor x\lfloor x\lfloor x\rfloor\rfloor\rfloor=2001$
Solve for $x$:
$x\lfloor x\lfloor x\lfloor x\rfloor\rfloor\rfloor=2001$
Given solution:
$\lfloor x\rfloor=\lfloor \sqrt[4]{2001}\rfloor=\{6,-7\}$
If $\lfloor x\rfloor=6\Rightarrow x\lfloor x\lfloor 6x\rfloor\rfloor=2001$
So far so good. Now the next step was too abrupt for me. The author has written
$\color{red}{\lfloor 6x\rfloor=\lfloor \sqrt[3]{(6)^2(2001)}\rfloor=41}$
$\Rightarrow x\lfloor 41x\rfloor=2001$
Now the author has used the same method as above and has written
$\color{red}{\lfloor 41x\rfloor=\lfloor \sqrt{(41)(2001)}\rfloor=286}$
and thus immediately arrives at the answer $x(286)=2001\Rightarrow x=\frac{2001}{286}$
How does $\color{red}{this}$ happen is what I would want to know. I am missing out on a basic result probably.
Though the question has a solution on StackExchange I want to know about the method I have described above which I find quite unique.
As the user @peterwhy pointed out in Comments the logic could have been $x\lfloor x\lfloor 6x\rfloor \rfloor =2001\Rightarrow 6x.6\lfloor x\lfloor 6x\rfloor \rfloor =6^2.2001$. Could this imply $\lfloor 6x\rfloor^3=6^2.2001\Rightarrow \lfloor 6x\rfloor=\lfloor \sqrt[3]{6^2.2001}\rfloor=41$

Maybe I'm missing something too. What book is this?

Shouldn't there be a negative solution ?

Apparently from $x\lfloor x\lfloor 6x\rfloor\rfloor = 2001$, the author would consider $6x\cdot6\lfloor x\lfloor 6x\rfloor\rfloor = (6)^2(2001)$ and immediately conclude $\lfloor 6x\rfloor=\left\lfloor \sqrt[3]{(6)^2(2001)}\right\rfloor$.

@peterwhy You mean $6x.6\lfloor x\lfloor 6x\rfloor \rfloor=\lfloor 6x\rfloor ^3$. How ?

Without some additional arguments this does not seem to be justified solution at all. If you apply the same steps to $x\lfloor x\lfloor x\lfloor x\rfloor\rfloor\rfloor=31$ you get $\frac{31}{11}$, which is not a solution. Instead we should get $x=\frac{31}{12}$.


Solve for $x$ where both: $$\begin{align*}
x\lfloor x\lfloor x\cdot 6\rfloor\rfloor &= 2001 \tag1\\
\lfloor x \rfloor &= 6 \tag2
\end{align*}$$

From the property that $\lfloor a \rfloor \le a$, the LHS of $(1)$ satisfies
$$\begin{align*}
x\lfloor x\lfloor x\cdot 6\rfloor\rfloor &\le x\cdot x\lfloor x\cdot 6\rfloor
\le x\cdot x\cdot x\cdot 6\\
x^3\cdot 6 &\ge 2001\\
x\cdot 6 &\ge \sqrt[3]{6^2\cdot2001} \approx 41.6
\end{align*}$$
From $(2)$,
$$\begin{align*}
6 \le x &< 7\\
x\cdot 6 &< 42
\end{align*}$$
So $\lfloor x\lfloor x\rfloor\rfloor = \lfloor x\cdot 6\rfloor = 41$.

Similarly, from $x\lfloor x\cdot41\rfloor = x\lfloor x\lfloor x\cdot 6\rfloor\rfloor = 2001$,
$$\begin{align*}
x^2 \cdot 41 &\ge x\lfloor x\cdot41\rfloor = 2001\\
x \cdot 41 &\ge \sqrt{41\cdot 2001} \approx 286.4
\end{align*}$$
And from the previous step,
$$\begin{align*}
41.6\ldots \le x \cdot6 &< 42\\
6.9\ldots \le x &< 7\\
284.3\ldots \le x\cdot 41 &< 287
\end{align*}$$
So $\lfloor x\lfloor x\lfloor x\rfloor\rfloor\rfloor = \lfloor x\cdot 41\rfloor = 286$.

One may say this step works, with $\lfloor x\cdot 6\rfloor$ narrowed down to one possibility, only because the lower and upper bounds of $x\cdot 6$ is near. This, I would agree.
This was also observed by some answers and comments in a similar question: find positive real number x that satisfies $2001=x\lfloor x\lfloor x\lfloor x\rfloor\rfloor\rfloor$.


For another example by @Sil, to solve for the positive $x$ where $$x\lfloor x\lfloor x\lfloor x\rfloor\rfloor\rfloor = 31$$

Here $\lfloor x\rfloor = \left\lfloor\sqrt[4]{31}\right\rfloor = 2$, then on one side $2x\ge \sqrt[3]{2^2\cdot 31} \approx 4.99$ while $2x < 2\cdot 3 = 6$. The possibilities for the next step is $\lfloor x\lfloor x\rfloor\rfloor = \lfloor 2x\rfloor \in\{4,5\}$:
$$\begin{array}{r|c|c}
\lfloor x\lfloor x\rfloor\rfloor = & 4 & 5 \\\hline
\text{Bounds from $x\lfloor x\rfloor$:}\\
x\cdot 2 = x\lfloor x\rfloor \in
& [4.99\ldots, 5)
& [5,6)\\
\overset{/2}{\implies} x \in
& \left[2.49\ldots, \frac52\right)
& \left[\frac52, \frac62\right)\\
\overset{\cdot \lfloor x\lfloor x\rfloor\rfloor}{\implies} x\lfloor x\lfloor x\rfloor\rfloor \in
& [9.97\ldots, 10)
& \left[12.5, 15\right)\\\hline
\text{Lower bound from the given:}\\
31 = x\lfloor x\lfloor x\lfloor x\rfloor\rfloor\rfloor \le x^2\lfloor x\lfloor x\rfloor\rfloor =
& 4x^2
& 5x^2\\
x\lfloor x\lfloor x\rfloor\rfloor \ge
& \sqrt{4\cdot31}\approx 11.1
& \sqrt{5\cdot31}\approx 12.4\\\hline
\lfloor x\lfloor x\lfloor x\rfloor\rfloor\rfloor \in
& \emptyset
& \{12,13,14\}
\end{array}$$
The next step even has 3 possibilities:
$$\begin{array}{r|c|c|c}
\lfloor x\lfloor x\lfloor x\rfloor\rfloor\rfloor =
& 12 & 13 & 14\\\hline
\text{Bounds from $x\lfloor x\lfloor x\rfloor\rfloor$:}\\
x\cdot 5 = x\lfloor x\lfloor x\rfloor\rfloor \in
& [12.5, 13)
& [13, 14)
& [14, 15)\\
\overset{/5}{\implies} x \in
& [2.5, 2.6)
& [2.6, 2.8)
& [2.8, 3)\\
\overset{\cdot \lfloor x\lfloor x\lfloor x\rfloor\rfloor\rfloor}{\implies} x\lfloor x\lfloor x\lfloor x\rfloor\rfloor\rfloor \in
& [30, 31.2)
& [33.8, 36.4)
& [39.2, 42)\\\hline
\text{From the given:}\\
x\lfloor x\lfloor x\lfloor x\rfloor\rfloor\rfloor = 
& 31
& 31
& 31\\
x = \frac{31}{\lfloor x\lfloor x\lfloor x\rfloor\rfloor\rfloor} =
& \frac{31}{12} \approx 2.5\\\hline
\text{Verifications:}\\
\lfloor x\rfloor = 
& \lfloor2.5\ldots\rfloor\\
\lfloor x\lfloor x\rfloor\rfloor = 
& \lfloor5.1\ldots\rfloor\\
\lfloor x\lfloor x\lfloor x\rfloor\rfloor\rfloor = 
& \lfloor12.91\ldots\rfloor
\end{array}$$
So the only positive solution $x$ is $\frac{31}{12}$, which has $\lfloor x\lfloor x\rfloor\rfloor = 5 \ne \left\lfloor\sqrt[3]{2^2\cdot 31}\right\rfloor = 4$.

Ok. So this means that the method shown in the book cannot be used blindly. Very enlightening answer.
